# Run script on shutdown but not reboot

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that works for what I want, which is to run a script when the system shuts down. However, this also runs on a reboot which is not what I want.

This is the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown script
Requires=network.target
Before=poweroff.target halt.target
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutSec=5
RemainAfterExit=true
User=sysadm
Group=sysadm
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/bin/myscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target systemd-halt.service systemd-poweroff.service
```

Is there any way to make this work for shutdowns only?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the most optimal solution, but it seems to do the trick.

I changed the `ExecStart` line as follows based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26593645/1586913) answer:

```
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c 'systemctl list-jobs | grep -Eq 'reboot.target.*start' || /usr/bin/myscript.sh'
```